# Is it correct third conditional sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is it grammatically correct?

> If this statement were correct/true then he would not have earned such fame.

I consider it 3rd conditional sentence, is it so?
If not correct then please tell me correct form.

Comment: If it were not a third conditional, it would not have 'would' in the sentence.  :)

Comment: When you start asking questions like this it is a clear sign that you have outgrown the notion of "first / second / third conditionals" constructions. They do not exhaust the possible conditional constructions; in fact, they don't even consistently have the meanings you have probably been taught. They are merely teaching devices, which should be discarded when they are no longer useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third conditional has the following form

> If + *past perfect tense*, would have + *past participle*.

So this would look like,

> If this statement *had been* true, then he would not *have earned* such fame.

So, since "were" is not past-perfect (it's past-progressive), we know it is not a third conditional sentence.

A second conditional sentence follows the form:

> If + *past progressive*, would + *infinitive*

So this would look like:

> If this statement *were* true, then he would *be* less famous.

Since "not have earned" is not an infinitive (and is in fact a past participle), we know it's not a second conditional sentence either.

I have good news though; there is such thing as a "mixed" conditional sentence... which this sentence is!

Comment: You don't believe in the subjunctive, then? That "not earning" sure seems like an irrealis to me.

Comment: I don't totally get what you're saying, @P.E.Dant. Are you saying that I should change my second conditional example to, "...he would not be earning such fame"?

Comment: If you were talking about the "were" thing I had up there, then you're right and I took it down. The subjunctive form is correct there. But I'm still not sure why you mentioned "not earning."

Comment: ...because the _not earning_ is the irrealis that reveals the subjunctive.

Comment: I see. I was confused because the actual sentence had the form, "would not have earned", instead of "not earning", so I thought you were trying to say something else.

Comment: I upvoted answer